How do you execute different commands with "the same keybinding" in vscode vim?
I used neovim for some time and I liked it. But now I want to go back to vscode because doing the configurations in neovim is a headache. But I still want to use vim motions.
I am trying to execute different commands with "the same keybinding".
Here is what I want to achieve but can't (keybindings.json file):
    {
      "key": "ctrl+e",
      "command": "workbench.explorer.fileView.focus",
      "when": "!sidebarVisible"
    },
    {
      "key": "ctrl+e",
      "command": "workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility",
      "when": "sidebarVisible"
    },

Here is what is working for me:
    {
      "key": "ctrl+z",
      "command": "workbench.explorer.fileView.focus",
    },
    {
      "key": "ctrl+e",
      "command": "workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility",
    }

I want to "toggle the sidebar" and also "focus the file explorer" with the same keybinding. I would also want to use the "Space" bar instead of ctrl but don't know why it is not working.
